# How to send timestamp in Express js json response?

Tags: json, node.js, date, express, timestamp

```
res.json({data: new Date()});
```

This is the response: `{data: '2014-05-20T01:40:34.993Z'}`

How to configure express to return timestamp instead of date string?

`{data: 1343235454545}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked out perfectly to filter all Date

```
app.set('json replacer', function (key, value) {
  if (this[key] instanceof Date) {
// Your own custom date serialization
value = this[key].now();
  }
  return value;

});
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `Date.now()`

Example - `res.json({data: Date.now()});`

Then you will get result in timestamp `"data": 1404359477253` likewise.

Comment: Yeah I know I can do that. But I want express to parse it into timestamp not to do it manually everytime.

Comment: @JunyuWu I don't seems a valid reason here for doing that(overriding the default)..you may use `dateformat` module or `moment.js` for formatting your date time display..at times you may need dates before 01.01.1970

Comment: I need timestamp in json response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js (as suggested by @swapnesh). But I found it more suitable to simply save the data as a timestamp. Since I'm using mongoDB I'm using Number for the data type.

So my schema looks something like this:

```
var myDataSchema = {
    start: {type: Number, required: "myDataSchema.start is a required field"},
}
```

This will output:

```
{
    "_id": "564c6828d4f028236cf1a6c8",
    "start": ​1450969200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`
Schema:({title:String},{timestamps:true})

`you can true the timestamps inside the model. I think problem solved

Comment: Please improve your answer with better indentation and code explanation